# Tree-sitter: "choice" grammar does not work

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, comments, compiler-optimization, treesitter

I use tree-sitter to write the parser for comment input.
this is the code I write for single line comment parsing:

```
seq(
    "//", 
    optional(seq($.comment_prefix, optional(/[ ]*/))), 
    /[^\n]*/ 
 ),
```

For the input string "@ TODO", it recognizes the comment_prefix and output as expected:

```
(source_file [0, 0] - [2, 0]
  (comment [0, 0] - [0, 8]
    (comment_prefix [0, 2] - [0, 8])))
```

However, for input string become "@ TODO this is a comment", it outputs:

```
(source_file [0, 0] - [2, 0]
  (comment [0, 0] - [0, 26]))
```

Why is the comment prefix no longer recognized if @TODO is followed by a string?

note: comment_prefix includes a range of annotations such as "@TODO", etc.